# Application started via cronjob succesfully but stops after sometime. No such issues when started manually

Tags: linux, bash, cron, filebeat

I have a filebeat instance running in one of my linux servers.
I have written a bash script to check if filebeat is running and if not restart it.
This bashscript is being invoked via crontab. It starts smoothly without any issue. But within a few minutes it stops.
At the same time if I manually run this script filebeat starts and runs for ages.
Can anybody guide me why am i getting such weird behaviour from crontab.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it your users crontab or the system one? in any case the user running the script via cron is not neccessarily your user, so it could be a permission issue

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog for the CRON entries. Maybe the script isn't executable? Or maybe the cron user doesn't have permissions to do the startup command? Perhaps put some extra debugging in your cron to test. HOWEVER why would you need to use cron to restart a service? You should have it enabled and if it's stopping for a reason you've got to resolve that in any case.